# Orbitals of hydrogen, superposition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, hydrogen, orbitals

I'm trying to find the time evolution of the following superposition states in the hydrogen atom:

$$\psi_- = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\psi_{1,0,0}+\psi_{2,1,-1}\right)
   \\\psi_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\psi_{1,0,0}+\psi_{2,1,0}\right)\\
   \psi_+ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\psi_{1,0,0}+\psi_{2,1,1}\right),$$

where $\psi_{n,l,m}$ are the stationary solutions to the Schrödinger Equation of hydrogen.

My idea is to multiply the wave functions which make up the superposition states with $\exp(-i\frac{E_nt}{\hbar})$ where $E_n = -\frac{1}{2n^2}\alpha^2m_ec^2$ is the energy of the $n$-th state (with $\alpha$ the fine-structure constant). But this whole exercise would be trivial then and there would be no difference between the different superposition states above because the energy does not depend on $l$ and $m$. So I think I'm missing something. Maybe someone can help me figure this out.

Comment: Note that at the fine and hyper-fine levels (neglected in the introductory treatment) the energy does depend on $l$ and $m$, so this exercise could be preparatory to looking at that or it might be formal test of your ability to recall and apply the basic rules of QM.

Comment: @dmckee So you think, my way to approach this is adequate? I don't think this exercise is about (hyper-)fine structure. The strange thing is that I'd have to put in only two different energies which seems too simple to me.

Comment: These states may have the same energy, but they *are* different in measurable ways.